# Reconstruct a URL string from sys.stdin in Python

Tags: python

I have a script that takes input from a large log file. This file has encoded URLs.
I am using standard input to grab these URLs from the file. I wish to process each URL separately.

Problem is when I get the a single URL its split up into each character in the URL. I do ''.join(something) when then after processing I get characters.

e.g.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line1 = ''.join(line)
```

I also tried collecting all the characters in the URL and then joining. Still same result.

Sample out I get:

Input from file:  " www.cnn.com"
output after sys.std and processing : ['w','w','w','.','c','n','n','.','c','o','m']

the list appears because i make it so. Otherwise i get www.cnn.com from sys.stdin. But the underlying structure is same as the output.

What I want is:
Input from file:  " www.cnn.com"
output: "www.cnn.com"  (this should be one string. not strings of individual characters)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted is the actual processing you do? Because it cannot generate the result that you are showing. The `join()` method returns a string, not a list.

Comment: I think the problem lies elsewhere in your script - `for line in sys.stdin: print repr(line.strip())` is fine, the join is unnecessary. It looks like somewhere you are doing `list(line)` or similar. Can you post more of the script?

Answer (score 1):

I think your stdin input might be garbled. Consider this script:

```
#stdin.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.strip()
```

Then piping input into it works as expected:

```
$ echo -e "www.cnn.com\nwww.test.com" | python stdin.py 
www.cnn.com
www.test.com
```

If you call `list()` on a string, it splits it up by character:

```
>>> list("test")
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

I'm guessing what you probably want to do is read the entire input and then split on lines, like this:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.read().split()
print lines
```

Running it, I get:

```
$ echo -e "www.cnn.com\nwww.test.com" | python stdin.py 
['www.cnn.com', 'www.test.com']
```

Comment: You are right but try doing this on the O/P of your script.

import sys

    for line in sys.stdin:
        l =  line.strip()
        l = list(l)
        print l






Let me know if you see something like this 

    ['w','w','w','.'....... 'o','m]

Comment: :) yes. thanks. But What I am trying to do is to read from a file.

cat /path/to/file/extention/ | python name.py

when it takes input from the file URL are passed as string so it says : 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. Apologies for being such a pain

Comment: sys.stdin should always be a file, not a string

Comment: This is what I am doing. Anything wrong ?  
for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()line1 = line.read() 
   test(dict_item_wrds3,line)

Comment: There are multiple lines in the file. as in multiple URLs each new URL in a new line

Comment: yes, that's wrong. you can't call ``line.read()`` on a string

Comment: yaah. I was trying out things. How do i read lines from a file using sys.stdin like the way i want to

Comment: exactly as I demonstrated in the post... ``for line in sys.stdin``. Just get rid of that ``line.read``

Comment: Do you I can split this resultant string based on some regex or will it give split it into individual parameters again ?